# How to set background color for some inner text of HTML textarea element?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, range

[image: facebook status]

It looks like selected some text, but the background color will not disappear when you click it or move cursor.

Comment: Use Firebug and analyze the HTML and CSS to see what they have done. There's probably more to it than just background color.

Comment: I usually use surroundContents method of Range to highlight text in HTML element, but it does not apply to the form element(it only supports plain text).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use textarea element for this.
Just make a contentEditable [contentEditable](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaScriptDemo/UsingthecontentEditableProperty.htm) div and use javascript to style it.

Comment: But I found that facebook did not use this method.

Comment: So, how does FB do it then? If you delete the textarea node, you can see the highlight remains - it's sitting behind the textarea. You can select it because it has invisible text! The highlight is actually a clone of the textarea content with font color set to transparent and the BG color set to the selection highlight color. The apppearance of a selection is really just a nifty visual effect going on in the background - facebook is not writing to or modifying the textarea at all apparently.

Answer (score 1):

It may be a `div` with [contentEditable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537837%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) set to true

Comment: I think so. But if do that, also need to think of a way for the low-end browsers.

Answer (score 0):

That could be a div the styled during events and as other suggested make it contentEditable. With regards to textarea I have read similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142527/highlight-text-inside-of-a-textarea). Check it if it's what your looking for.

Comment: textarea { posision: absolute; background: transparent }
div { posision: absolute; color: transparent }
div b { background: gray }