# colorize text in textarea with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, textarea

i need to colorize **part** of the text in textarea. Let's say first line in red, second in blue. How to do this? (jQuery)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not sure if it possible with textarea. Instead use div [contentEditable](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/WD-html5-20080610/editing.html).

See similar questions

[Rendering HTML inside textarea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4705848/rendering-html-inside-textarea)

[How to set background color for some inner text of HTML textarea element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5470671/how-to-set-background-color-for-some-inner-text-of-html-textarea-element/5470994#5470994)

Answer (score 0):

You can't easily style the contents of a text area, you can however use a simplified rich text editor to accomplish this.

something like RTE: http://batiste.dosimple.ch/blog/posts/2007-09-11-1/rich-text-editor-jquery.html
or CLEditor: http://premiumsoftware.net/cleditor/ would be a good starting point for this.