# How to modify some data inside textbox area

Tags: php, html, css, textbox

I have some textbox. Between `<textarea> </textarea>` I inserting two values $firstname, $lastname. Now I'd like to make bold only $firstname. 
When I'm trying this code below it is doesn't working.

```
"<textarea><b>" . $firstname. "</b>" . $lastname . "<textarea>"
```

How can I do it correctly. Is it possible? When I am using `<div>` tags it's doesn't working too.

Comment: there's no html tag called textbox. you're probably looking for textarea

Comment: Sorry my bad, of course, textarea

Comment: i Wouldnt expect this to be possible inside a textarea to be honest

Comment: possible duplicate of [colorize text in textarea with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5498005/colorize-text-in-textarea-with-jquery)

Comment: Thank you for all your help, I found jQuery code, and it's working.
http://www.strangeplanet.fr/work/jquery-highlighttextarea/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don´t use HTML inside textareas, they just take plain text.

Check some WYSIWYG(What You See Is What You Get) that may help you:

http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/design/10-best-wysiwyg-text-and-html-editors-for-your-next-project/

Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

You should look at the [contenteditable](http://html5demos.com/contenteditable) attribute on generic elements like DIVs.

Answer (score 0):

Textarea only takes plain text. If you want to use html you should take a look wysiwyg editors .