# Select text in GWT

Tags: javascript, gwt, java-native-interface

I want to select a text in GWT:

I have a method which select the text in Firefox but bug in Chrome:

```
public native void markThisText(Element elem) /*-{
        if ($doc.selection && $doc.selection.createRange) {
            var range = $doc.selection.createRange();
            range.moveToElementText(elem);
            range.select();
        } else if ($doc.createRange && $wnd.getSelection) {
            var range = $doc.createRange();
            range.selectNode(elem);
            var selection = $wnd.getSelection();
            selection.removeAllRanges();
            selection.addRange(range);
        }
}-*/;
```

Error log :

```
Caused by: com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptException: (INVALID_NODE_TYPE_ERR):  
INVALID_NODE_TYPE_ERR: DOM Range Exception 2    at    com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invokeJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.java:248
)   at   
com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpaceOOPHM.doInvoke(ModuleSpaceOOPHM.java:136)   at  
com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNative(ModuleSpace.java:561)     at 
com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNativeVoid(ModuleSpace.java:289)     at 
com.google.gwt.dev.shell.JavaScriptHost.invokeNativeVoid(JavaScriptHost.java:107)
```

Do you know why? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may find this helpful:

[Highlight text inside of a textarea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142527/highlight-text-inside-of-a-textarea)

Comment: Your example get a taxt selected and not select a text, isn't it?

And i've got a "Cannot read property 'getSelection" of undefined"

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the question. Take a look at the similar question - it has a good answer.

Comment: It's not hep me very much... As i read on the web, there is an issue for webkit browsers (safari and chrome) with range.setNode...