# Highlight text in a textarea across multiple lines

Tags: javascript

Referring to https://stackoverflow.com/a/7599199 - Highlight text in a textarea.  I need to highlight text between markers.  The below works great for a single line but I need to span multiple lines. I can't seem to figure out the correct code to add.  Any ideas?

example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#body_cfm").highlightTextarea({
       words: ["<\!---((.|\)*)--->"],

  });
});
```

Comment: Can you show an example in jsfiddle ?

Answer (score 0):

`.` does not account for a newline.  Create a character class that includes newlines.

```
<\!---(([.\n]|\)*)--->
```