# How to change the background color of a line of user input in a textarea?

Tags: css, input, textarea, background-color

I know how to change the background color of a textarea, but what about changing the background color of the **text** that users type into a text area?

For example, in HTML you can change the background color of a span of text using span tags, ie:

```
<span style="background-color: blue">Words with blue background</span>
```

...But what about the text that users type into a text field?

I need to do this for a form that I'm creating, so that users can clearly see spaces and returns they're entering as well as the characters they enter.

Can it be done using CSS?

Comment: Check this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/142527/highlight-text-inside-of-a-textarea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

But there is the other way around.
Did you ever used editor in github.com? It's cool.
It uses javascript and <div> to control the style of each line of code.
And translate.google.com uses the same way.