# highlight specific words in textarea similar to gmail spell check bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, django

basically, I would like to **develop** a django based application for a synonym dictionary, where the user can write a paragraph and my application, highlights a set of words in different colors and by clicking on those highlight words, a set of synonym will be shown as a popup box (exactly like gmail spell checker) and by clicking they get replaced by the word.

The main question is from where should I start. Is there any API that can assist me ? Also, I wonder, if such a editable area is still called "textarea" ? What library are already out there to help me me out with coloring and pop-up box or any similar code ?

I appreciate any hint.

Comment: you could have granted me with you down vote after making comment ! I clearly didn't ask for work or etc. The question is what are the bases and from where should I start - I dont understand why so many angry people are here ...

Comment: i think you'll be able to find answers over [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/142527/highlight-text-inside-of-a-textarea/142562#142562)