# Highlight a particular word in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to highlight a particular word in a textarea.
I know how to do it for the entire division, but don't know how to do it for a specific word.

```
document.getElementById("labnol").style.backgroundColor = "lightblue";
```

This is what I have tried to highlight the entire `div` .But now want to do it for a specific word.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! A quick search will point you here which provides several answers to your question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/142527/highlight-text-inside-of-a-textarea

Answer (score 0):

You have to create `span` element for that word with class `ui-match`(can be any class name)

**HTML**

```
  <p> 
       Hello <span class="ui-match">there</span>, How are you?
  </p>
```

**CSS**

```
 .ui-match {
     background: #FF0;
  }
```