# Highlighting input in textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to achieve a highlight effect in my textarea, basically as a user types a sentence, a background color is being added, similar to this effect: http://jsbin.com/josatozeyi/1/edit (I know it's the resizing of textarea but is there any other way?)

```
<textarea class='animated'>With CSS transition.</textarea>
```

Any suggestions?

**ADDITIONAL INFO**
This is what I meant: http://prntscr.com/63xdi9

Comment: Is it OK to add s `<span>` into the `<textarea>`?

Comment: As long as it achieves the desired result and doesn't mess up the functionality of textarea then yes :)

Comment: i guess that's no if you use this textarea in a real form and can be submitted.

Comment: Yes, you're right  I will be using the textarea in a form. I can't really think of anything either

Comment: possible duplicate of [Highlight text inside of a textarea](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/142527/highlight-text-inside-of-a-textarea)

Answer (score 1):

It's too complicated to me, however I found this, it might be useful:

> highlightTextarea aim is to highlight portions of text into a textarea
>   or a input. It can highlight a set of words or a specific range.

http://mistic100.github.io/jquery-highlighttextarea/

Source: [mistic100](https://github.com/mistic100/jquery-highlighttextarea)

Answer (score 0):

Add a css rule that adds a background color to the textarea on focus.

```
input:focus { 
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

Comment: Hi, this just makes the entire textarea background yellow, rather than just the text's specific background.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the affect you want with `contenteditable` span element, and then applying a background color on focus: http://jsfiddle.net/13L9zudf/

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var defaultVal = "Type content here...";
  $("div.textbox span").keyup(function(){
      if($(this).html() == "")
      {
        $(this).html(defaultVal);
      }
    }).keydown(function(){
      if($(this).html() == defaultVal)
      {
        $(this).html("");
      }
    });
  });
```

```css
div.textbox {
  border: 1px #000 solid;
  padding: .5em;
  width: 30em;
  height: 10em;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
div.textbox span {
  line-height: 1.5em;
  max-width:30em;
  display: inline-block;
}
div.textbox span:focus {
  background: #ff0;
  border:0;
  outline: 0;
}
div.textbox span:active {
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="textbox">
<span contenteditable="true">Type content here...</span>
</div>
```

Comment: What exactly about this doesn't work for your situation? Does it need more padding on the highlighting? A visible box around the text? I'm not sure how what I posted doesn't answer your question

Comment: Oh, well firstly it's a really odd textarea, it seems like every time I press enter a new textarea is created, secondly. Instead of highlighting the specific text only it seems to highlight the entire textarea box (perhaps this could be padding problem?). ALSO I'm not downgrading your answer at all, I really appreciate you helping!

Comment: The tricky part of what you're asking is the text highlighting, the rest is all CSS styling, just matter of using css to get how you want it to look; I added a bit of the basics that's more what you were looking for